# Standard doping concentrations for Si and GaAs Solar Cell (as well as other standard values)

Tags: diodes, solar-cell, photodiode

I am doing a MATLAB project where I need to plot the current of a Silicon and GaAs Solar Cell under Air Mass 0 and Air Mass 1 conditions. I have used solar irradiance data to calculate their photocurrent density (\$I_L/A\$) and am now attempting to plot their I-V curves using these two formulas:

[image]

and

[image]

I currently have \$I_L/A\$. But I need to find standard values for A, \$N_c\$, \$N_v\$, \$N_c\$, \$N_d\$, \$D_n\$, \$D_p\$, \$\tau_n\$, and \$\tau_p\$ for GaAs and Si photodiodes.

I have Googled for such specs and it seems no one has a simple example of standard values for these photodiodes so I am wondering if someone here could give me some standard values or refer me to a website that has them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Note:** Question as originally posted asked about a photodiode, not a solar cell.

If you are not designing the device yourself, you don't need to know all those values. Most photodiodes you buy will simply have a dark current spec. If you need to know how this varies with reverse bias, you can work out *I<sub>s</sub>* from the dark current and the measurement conditions (*V* and *T*).

For example, Fairchild [QSD2030](http://www.fairchildsemi.com/ds/QS/QSD2030.pdf) specifies a dark current of 10 nA with 10 V reverse bias at 25 C. Given the specified reverse bias is so high, we know this dark current is essentially equal to *I<sub>s</sub>*, so we know *I<sub>s</sub>* ~= 10 nA.

**Edit**

Okay, so you really want to get those values as an academic excercise.

*A* is just the area of the device. It can be whatever you design it to be.

*D<sub>n</sub>*, *D<sub>p</sub>* are the diffusion coefficients. You can get them from your textbook or from the [Ioffe Institute](http://www.ioffe.ru/SVA/NSM/Semicond/Si/electric.html)

*τ<sub>n</sub>* and *τ<sub>p</sub>* are the carrier lifetimes. You can also find these values at the Ioffe Institute site.

*N<sub>d</sub>* and *N<sub>a</sub>* are the donor and acceptor doping concentrations. You could design these however you like. Numbers between 10<sup>15</sup> and 10<sup>20</sup> are at least soft of reasonable.

The product *N<sub>c</sub>N<sub>v</sub>* is equal to *n<sub>i</sub><sup>2</sup>*, the square of the intrinsic carrier concentration. You can also get this value from the Ioffe Institute on [another page](http://www.ioffe.ru/SVA/NSM/Semicond/Si/bandstr.html).

Comment: I realize that i wouldnt normally need to know these, but for the purposes of this project i am asked to find standard values for these and use them to make these curves. Trust me, i wouldn't bother trying so hard to find these if i didn't have to.

Comment: Thanks for the edit! This is super useful. a couple questions though, first Nd and Na are just doping concentrations, if they are equal is there an issue or is it okay for them to both, say, be 10^16? and shouldnt Si and GaAs have different doping levels, or do they operate at around the same doping levels?

Secondly, is there a reason i shouldnt use the graph at the very bottom for tau_n and tau_p? you said i can get them from a relationship with mobility, but they seem to also be listed (with diffusion length) at the very bottom of the page.

Comment: Typical devices in GaAs might use different doping levels---I am not a device designer so I don't know values off the top of my head or even where to look for them (maybe in some papers describing new device designs?) As for the τ values there are two different τ's. One is related to recombination (the one in the plots you found) and the other is related to scattering (the one connected to mobility). To be honest now I'm not sure which one you want to use in your formula.

Comment: Wikipedia says you want the carrier lifetime, not the scattering time, so yes, use the plots at Ioffe, not the mobility value.

Answer (score 1):

To add to The Photons answer. The primary parameter that solar cell designers (process people) are concerned about is carrier lifetime.  This is understandable in that to get high internal QE you want your depletion regions as large (deep ) as possible, which means that the doping must be very light.  That means that the doping concentration is not as flexible as you might think.  The lifetime will be dominated by the impurity levels.  I remember times of 1 ms being obtained, but do verify this.  I will note that you don't have any equations for junction depth and this QE so your model is incomplete.

Comment: would you care to suggest some standard values (if you know them) for doping so i can look up the corresponding carrier lifetimes?

Answer (score 1):

For thin-film Si standard values for base (Na) is ~5e16 (units are 'per cubic centimetre' expressed /cm3 or cm-3) and for the emitter Nd ~1e19 cm-3.

P.S. There is a software program called PC1D which is made for problems like this. For a one-dimensional simulation it is very powerful.